# How to get road labels on Stamen Watercolor basemap in Cartodb

Tags: carto, labeling, basemap

basic question here.  I want to use the Stamen Watercolor basemap on CartoDB, but want the road and locality labels displayed on it, as at http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/stamen.html?q=watercolor.

Could anyone talk me through how to get the road labels on there, from the Watercolor basemap or another source? The map will be of the UK.